# How to start automatically installation after download completed from server(desktop application)

Tags: windows, winforms, installation, desktop-application

I have one desktop application.

And this application is upload on server and i will generate one downloadable link. and after download finished i want to start installation automatically.

if you have any solution about like this so please share with us.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot run a process without user consent.

Comment: I am not getting exactly. can you please share more detail.